# Can't load local images from public folder when using different loader | NEXT.JS

Tags: next.js

```
...    
    loader: "akamai",
    path: "",
  },
```

I'm using akamai loader since I can't use `next export`, but when I use Image component

```
 <Image
        src={"/example.png"}
        layout={"fill"}
        objectFit={"cover"}
        alt={"phone"}
        quality={100}
      />
```

it does not work. But when I use next.js image loader it works.